# Plotting a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame after reactive subsetting in Leaflet for Shiny retunrs an error when the SPDF is empty

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

So I've got a shiny map up and running using geoJSON data for all US counties. I have some attached metrics to each of these counties so I'm essentially working with SpatialPolygonsDataFrames. The map currently takes some input (avg. volume, etc.) and filters the geoJSON data so the map only renders the counties that pass the filter. I'm trying to figure out how to deal with the situation where the filters end up removing all the county polygons (i.e, none of the counties pass the filter). Right now, the map just crashes when that happens and returns this error:

> Warning in polygonData.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(data) :   Empty
>   SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object passed and will be skipped
>
> Warning: Error in sum: invalid 'type' (list) of argument   [No stack
>   trace available]

The relevant parts of the code are here: `global.R`:

```
data_sets <- list(countyborder2006,
                  countyborder2007,
                  countyborder2008,
                  countyborder2009,
                  countyborder2010,
                  countyborder2011,
                  countyborder2012,
                  countyborder2013,
                  countyborder2014,
                  countyborder2015,
                  countyborder2016,
                  countyborder2017,
                  countyborder2018,
                  countyborder_all)
```

`ui.R`:

```
conditionalPanel("input.level == 'County level'",

                 selectInput("year", "Year:",
                             choices = c("2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011", "2012",
                                         "2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018", "All years" = "2019"),
                             selected = "2019"
                 ),
                 numericInput("opcrange", 
                              label = "Minimum ops vol:",
                              min = 0, max = 10000000, value = 0
                 ),
                 numericInput("opppcrange",
                                               label = "Minimum ops ppa:",
                                               min = 0, max = 150, value = 0
                                  )
                 ),                  
                 numericInput("oppcrange",
                              label = "Minimum % of ops:",
                              min = -1, max = 1, value = -1
                 ),
                 numericInput("ohpcrange",
                              label = "Minimum % of others:",
                              min = -1, max = 1, value = -1)
)
```

`server.R`:

```
# filter data according to parameters set for customer level
  filteredData <- reactive({
    req(input$opcrange)
    req(input$opppcrange)
    req(input$oppcrange)
    req(input$ohpcrange)
    else if (input$level == "County level") {
      countyborder <- data_sets[[(as.numeric(input$year) - 2005)]]
      if (input$oporoh == "Opioids") {
        countyborder[countyborder@data$avg_opioid >= input$opcrange &
                       countyborder@data$avg_oxy_hydro >= input$ohcrange &
                       countyborder@data$avg_opioid_ppp >= input$opppcrange &
                       countyborder@data$avg_opioid_perc >= input$oppcrange &
                       countyborder@data$avg_oxy_hydro_perc >= input$ohpcrange,]
      } else {
        countyborder[countyborder@data$avg_opioid >= input$opcrange &
                       countyborder@data$avg_oxy_hydro >= input$ohcrange &
                       countyborder@data$avg_oxy_hydro_ppp >= input$ohppcrange &
                       countyborder@data$avg_opioid_perc >= input$oppcrange &
                       countyborder@data$avg_oxy_hydro_perc >= input$ohpcrange,]
      }
    }
  })

# render base map that isn't redrawn every time
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron",
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%  #Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      setView(-99, 45, zoom = 4) %>% #set view over US
      addScaleBar(position = "topleft") %>%
      addMeasure(position = "topleft")
  })

  # this observer controls all the markers for customer level info
  observe({
    else if (input$level == "County level") {
      withProgress(message = "Rendering...", value = 0.1, {
          pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", bins = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 20, Inf), filteredData()$avg_ops_ppp,pretty = FALSE)

          leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
            clearMarkers() %>%
            clearMarkerClusters() %>%
            clearShapes() %>%
            addPolygons(
              stroke = TRUE,
              color = "white",
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                weight = 2,
                fillOpacity = 0.6,
                color = "#666",
                opacity = 0.8,
                bringToFront = TRUE,
                sendToBack = TRUE
              ),
              opacity = 1,
              weight = 0.5,
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              fillColor = pal(filteredData()$avg_ops_ppp),
              label = lapply(countyInfo, HTML)
            ) %>%
            clearControls() %>%
            addLegend(
              "bottomleft",
              pal = pal,
              values = filteredData()$avg_ops_ppp,
              title = "Ops ppa per month",
              layerId = "countyLegend"
            )
      })
    }
  })
```

I have tried using a conditional to not map anything using `if (is.data.frame(countyborder@data) & nrow(countyborder@data) == 0) {}` but that doesn't seem to work either. Are there any other workarounds for this? Unfortunately, I cannot share the data but the county shape files are from http://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/.

Comment: You could add a `req(filteredData ())` in your last observer. But why are you starting your conditionals with else if ?

Comment: Oh there are if blocks above these else ifs but I didn't include them since it was getting a bit cluttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using a conditional like so:

```
 observe({
    else if (input$level == "County level") {
      withProgress(message = "Rendering...", value = 0.1, {
       if (is.data.frame(filteredData()@data) & nrow(filteredData()@data) == 0){
        leafletProxy("map") %>%
          clearMarkers() %>%
          clearMarkerClusters() %>%
          clearShapes()
         } else {
          pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", bins = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 20, Inf), filteredData()$avg_ops_ppp,pretty = FALSE)

          leafletProxy("map", data = filteredData()) %>%
            clearMarkers() %>%
            clearMarkerClusters() %>%
            clearShapes() %>%
            addPolygons(
              stroke = TRUE,
              color = "white",
              highlight = highlightOptions(
                weight = 2,
                fillOpacity = 0.6,
                color = "#666",
                opacity = 0.8,
                bringToFront = TRUE,
                sendToBack = TRUE
              ),
              opacity = 1,
              weight = 0.5,
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              fillColor = pal(filteredData()$avg_ops_ppp),
              label = lapply(countyInfo, HTML)
            ) %>%
            clearControls() %>%
            addLegend(
              "bottomleft",
              pal = pal,
              values = filteredData()$avg_ops_ppp,
              title = "Ops ppa per month",
              layerId = "countyLegend"
            )
         }
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: I wonder how that works, as you test for `nrow(filteredData()@data) == 0`. So if the number of rows in the dataset is 0, what does it plot? I just included the `nrow` approach in my answer.

Comment: Since `nrow` is 0, the conditional is just clearing all the previous shapes. The base map is still rendered by the first `output$map` call. The `req(nrow(filteredData()@data) != 0)` in your edited comment could work. My fault here for not including the first `if` block since that isn't a SPDF so it returns an error when attempting to find the `@data` slot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
req(filteredData())
```

or

```
req(filteredData()@data)
```

or

```
req(length(filteredData()@data) != 0)
```

or

```
req(nrow(filteredData()@data) != 0)
```

(depending on your reactive dataset), at the beginning of your last observer, which adds the polygons to the leaflet map.

This will stop the execution, if no data is left to plot.

Or according to the `req()` docs:

> If any of the given values is not truthy, the operation is stopped by
>   raising a "silent" exception

Comment: `req(filteredData())` doesn't work here since the filtering the data still returns an object (just without anything in the `@data` slot). I still get the same error.

Comment: I just added some alternatives. They all use `req`, but specify different conditions. You can try out the ones I mentioned or experiment with other options. You could include a `browser()` at the top of the observer and test which condition would work, if the dataset is empty.

Comment: This is super weird since I expected those to work but they don't seem to be working for some reason (still returns the same error). Still appreciate you trying!

Comment: Hm, maybe  also test `req(filteredData()$avg_ops_ppp)`. The thing is, I cannot really debug your problem. Having a reproducible example would make it much easier, as the problem might also be hidden somewhere else.. Also I dont know where your second warning really comes from.

Comment: I take the blame since I can't share the data but I just posted my solution. Thanks for the help!